# Failed to add data to database

Tags: php, html, pastebin

im trying to add data to a database, via a form i have created, but i just can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone please help me?

I have included some of the code, which i think is the problem, but also included a pastbin link to all the code.

https://pastebin.com/PpfCvjhf

```html
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
            $grafik_name = $_POST['grafik_name'];
            $grafik_coin = $_POST['grafik_coin'];
            $grafik_hashrate = $_POST['grafik_hashrate'];
            $grafik_bios_mod = $_POST['grafik_bios_mod'];
            $grafik_core_clock = $_POST['grafik_core_clock'];
            $grafik_memory_clock = $_POST['grafik_memory_clock'];
            $grafik_power_draw = $_POST['grafik_power_draw'];
            $grafik_additional_info = $_POST['grafik_additional_info'];

            
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `cards` (`id`, `name`, `coin`, `hashrate`, `bios_mod`, `core_clock`, `memory_clock`, `power_draw`, `additional_info`) VALUES ('$user_id','$grafik_name','$grafik_coin','$grafik_hashrate','$grafik_bios_mod','$grafik_core_clock','$grafik_memory_clock','$grafik_power_draw','$grafik_additional_info', NOW())";
               
            mysql_select_db('grafik');
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

```
<?php
```

https://pastebin.com/PpfCvjhf

Comment: Hello. Before we look at your problem, I recommend you to visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Right now your code is really vulnerable to injections and not save at all, your database could be hacked in a few seconds without any need of deeper knowledge of your system. You should ALWAYS use prepared statements when handling queries with user inputs. At bobby-tables you can learn how to use them - its really easy, please do that. Also don't use `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated and not longer supported in PHP7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_*`

Comment: @twinfriends im aware of how vulnerable my code is, but right now that isnt a problem, im going to work on that, when i get the code to work.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. I know a lot of people are working like you. I see it everyday, so many people say "Don't worry I'll do that once the code works" - NO! To write a prepared statement takes you 30 seconds more than a non-prepared statement. Why not do it directly? You'll run in more problems when you try to change it after. I don't get it why people don't want to use prepared statements straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Error in this query :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `cards` (`id`, `name`, `coin`, `hashrate`, `bios_mod`, `core_clock`, `memory_clock`, `power_draw`, `additional_info`) VALUES ('$user_id','$grafik_name','$grafik_coin','$grafik_hashrate','$grafik_bios_mod','$grafik_core_clock','$grafik_memory_clock','$grafik_power_draw','$grafik_additional_info', NOW())";
```

Number of columns is less than values !!

Comment: Could you maybe try and correct the code for me, because i cant seem to find the error you are talking about

Comment: where is column name for `NOW()`, available in VALUES ? @ChristianFrandsen

Comment: Ohh thanks. i just fixed that, and now its giving me another error. "could not enter data". From the code `(if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error());
            }` It just dosent seem to output the sql error.

Comment: it seems that an extra bracket before `if` see `(if` @ChristianFrandsen

Answer (score 0):

1. Column count doesn't match value.
   The problem is : `NOW())` take a look carefully. Remove the `NOW())`
2. Your query i think wrong.
   The right one is, `$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES ('$values1', '$values2')";`